# One-To-Many Merge with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given two dataframes in which two keys share a centralised value in another dataframe as follows:

| manager_id | employee_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 9 |

| employee_id | location |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | US |
| 2 | France |
| 3 | UK |
| 4 | Russia |
| 5 | Mexico |
| 6 | Spain |
| 7 | Italy |
| 8 | Greece |
| 9 | Hungary |

how to merge with pandas the key in the second dataframe to the other two in the first one so it ends up as follows:

| manager_id | employee_id | manager_location | employee_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | US | Mexico |
| 4 | 3 | Russia | UK |
| 4 | 2 | Russia | France |
| 7 | 9 | Italy | Hungary |

to be clear, both manager_id and employee_id share the same id key in the location table, even if they have distinct names.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` ids to locations by converting the DataFrame with location data `df2` into a Series where indices are employee_ids and values are locations:

```
id_to_location_mapper = df2.set_index('employee_id')['location']
df1['manager_location'] = df1['manager_id'].map(id_to_location_mapper)
df1['employee_location'] = df1['employee_id'].map(id_to_location_mapper)
```

You can also `unstack`, `map`, `unstack` and `join`:

```
df1 = df1.join(df1.unstack().map(df2.set_index('employee_id')['location']).swaplevel().unstack().add_suffix('_location'))
```

Output:

```
   manager_id  employee_id manager_location employee_location
0           1            5               US            Mexico
1           4            3           Russia                UK
2           4            2           Russia            France
3           7            9            Italy           Hungary
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround but I was mainly looking out for a direct merge with possibly a prefix that you can add instead of having to manually create a column and mapping.

Comment: @lorenzoDM you want to construct 2 columns, so I guess there will be some manual work before any merging. See if the updated solution suits to your needs.